# iPad 2 iOS5, localStorage QUOTA_EXEEDED_ERR

Tags: ios5, local-storage, ipad-2

Is anyone else having issues with localStorage on iPad 2 with iOS5?

I keep getting QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR even on a basic page suc as this on my iPad: http://jsfiddle.net/dmK7w/2/

Removing the item then setting the item doesn't fix it. There's nothing in the localStorage either as I've cleared that first too :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the new data storage guidelines. 
Maybe that will help. I suspect the limits have shrunk a bit since iOS5.

**Blog article about the matter**

http://www.marco.org/2011/10/13/ios5-caches-cleaning

**Apple's official dev-site:**

https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/

Comment: Let me just add that iOS 5.0.1 introduced some new ways of telling your app not to back up files to the cloud, and therefore ignore any restrictions in that regard: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html